# Sumar una columna con horas a una columna con fechas y obtener el resultado en una columna nueva (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, date

Tengo un dataset el cual me brinda las horas en las que se realizaron ciertas transacciones bancarias.
La hora cero corresponde al inicio del mes, el día 01/09/2022 a las 7 A.M.
Como input tengo la columna hora y la columna fecha(que se repite para todas las filas), necesito poder iterar tanto la columna fecha como la columna hora para poder crear la columna fecha final, que es el resultado de sumar la columna hora a la columna fecha.

| hora | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 07:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-09-01 07:00:00 |
| 3 | 2022-09-01 07:00:00 |
| 4 | 2022-09-01 07:00:00 |
| 5 | 2022-09-01 07:00:00 |

Intente esta sentencia para probar con la primer fila , pero no comprendo como hacer para iterar
sobre la columna hora y que sume a la columna fecha:

df_fechas['fecha_final'] = df_fechas["fecha"]  + pd.Timedelta(hours = df_fechas["hora"][1])

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

fecha = datetime(2022, 1, 1, 7)

df = pd.DataFrame([(fecha, i) for i in range(1, 10)], columns=["fecha", "hora"])

df["fecha_final"] = df["fecha"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["hora"], 'h')

print(df)
```

Produce:

```
                fecha  hora         fecha_final
0 2022-01-01 07:00:00     1 2022-01-01 08:00:00
1 2022-01-01 07:00:00     2 2022-01-01 09:00:00
2 2022-01-01 07:00:00     3 2022-01-01 10:00:00
3 2022-01-01 07:00:00     4 2022-01-01 11:00:00
4 2022-01-01 07:00:00     5 2022-01-01 12:00:00
5 2022-01-01 07:00:00     6 2022-01-01 13:00:00
6 2022-01-01 07:00:00     7 2022-01-01 14:00:00
7 2022-01-01 07:00:00     8 2022-01-01 15:00:00
8 2022-01-01 07:00:00     9 2022-01-01 16:00:00
```

Este código genera un dataframe cuya columna fecha tiene la fecha 2022-01-01 a las 7:00 y en la columna hora un número del 1 al 10 (no inclusive). Luego creamos una columna fecha final que resultará de la columna fecha más una serie de timedeltas.

Para lograr esto ultimo, utilizamos la función [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), para convertir la hora en objetos timedelta que están conformados por tantas horas como indica la columna y es posible sumarlos a la fecha.

Comment: Funciono a la perfección! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Me alegro de que funcionase c: Me podés apoyar aceptando la respuesta, además de que la comunidad tendrá más claro que preguntas ya estan resueltas y cuales no nwn